# How to replace multiple values in a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to turn N number of zeros into a "1". My code works to change only one zero at a time. What is the best way to simultaneously change the zeros into a "1" N number of times?

```
N=4;
board=zeros(N);
board(randi(numel(board)))=1
```

Thank you

Edit:

```
N=4;
board=zeros(N);
x=1;
while (x<=N)
    board(randi(numel(board)))=1;
    x=x+1;
end
```

Would it be possible to get this to work? It's not giving me an error, but it's not giving me an output either...

Comment: So you want to randomly change N 0s to 1s?

Comment: Yes, randomly changed throughout the matrix. I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting a small improvement over atru's answer. All you need to do is this:

```
N=4;
board=zeros(N);
board(randperm(numel(board), N)) = 1;
```

Here `randperm` will basically generate N random numbers from the set 1:(N*N) to fill your matrix

Comment: Indeed, this is more elegant and feels more random! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it while avoiding an explicit `for` loop

```
N=4;
board=zeros(N);

ind_1s = randperm(N*N);
board(ind_1s(1:N)) = 1;
```

This generates random permutations of all matrix indices and then it fills first `N` with 1s.

Your solution will work too but it needs a condition for cases when the newly chosen index already has a `1` in there

```
N=4;
board=zeros(N);
x=1;
while (x<=N)
    ind_1s = randi(numel(board));
    if board(ind_1s)==0
        board(ind_1s)=1;
        x=x+1;
    end
end
```

For large matrices the first one may be better performance wise, but that would need to be check with matlab profiler or simple timing.

Comment: Is there a way to control the number of 1s that are produced? I adjusted to lim = 0.25, but the number of 1s that appear seem almost random rather than being constrained by N

Comment: Yes, it's going to be random. There are more ways to do it - so you want a fixed, upfront known number?

Comment: I'm trying to do random placement, but with an amount that's constrained to N. In this case, I would only like four 1s to appear in random places. If N was 5, I would need five 1s to appear in random places, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an `NxN` matrix of 0s with `M` randomly placed 1s in a single line

```
myMatrix = reshape(randperm(N^2)<=M, N, N);
```

Just replace `M` with `N` in your specific case.